# How to format date with T parameter in between in java?

Tags: android, date, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

I have a date in this format - `01 May 2020`, and I want to parse it in the following format - `2020-05-01T00:00:00`. I am using the following code -

```
static String convertDateStringFormat(String dateString, String originalDateFormat, String outputDateFormat){
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(originalDateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date input = null;
        try {
            input = inputFormat.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputDateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
        return outputFormat.format(input);
    }
```

and I am passing the arguments as - `convertDateStringFormat("01 May 2020", "dd MMM yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")`. I dont know what I am doing wrong but it gives me this exception - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 2020-05-01T00:00:00`, so it looks like it is converting to the right format and then throwing an exception?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Posted code returns `2020-05-01T00:00:00` with posted arguments. Are you certain this is the code throwing that exception? Also, you **should** rewrite this code with the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: yes , this is the exact code I have used in my project. One more thing I am doing is, putting the returned String value from this method inside a java.util.Date Constructor

Comment: That won't work. Date doesn't take a formatted string like that. Your posted code works fine.

Comment: Also note that when you convert it to a `Date`, the format will be lost anyway, so there would be no need to convert it in that case.

Comment: Oh ok, so I misunderstood where the real problem was. Thankyou.

Comment: One more question, how would I get a Date object of this date string? I was using this method because I have 2 different date formats I need to compare?

Comment: `inputFormat.parse(dateString);` returns a `Date` object.

Comment: okay, I was under the impression I would have to change the format first and then convert it to Date object.

Comment: Even on Android and even on older Android versions do consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @OleV.V. ok, thankyou, will look into it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a format using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with `hour` defaulted to `0` and then parse the date string into `LocalDateTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy"))
                                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                                    .toFormatter();

        String strDate = "01 May 2020";
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, format);

        DateTimeFormatter targetFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String strDateInTargetFormat = date.format(targetFormat);

        System.out.println(strDateInTargetFormat);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-05-01T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse( 
    "01 May 2020" , 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern( "dd MMMM uuuu" )
    .withLocale( Locale.US ) 
)
.atStartOfDay(
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/bl7L1O).

> 2020-05-01T00:00:00

## Details

You said:

> I have a date in this format - 01 May 2020

That means you have text, a `String`, *not* a date. Date-time objects do not have a “format”.

Parse your text as a `LocalDate`.

```
String input = "01 May 2020" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMMM uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

You said:

> want to parse it in the following format - 2020-05-01T00:00:00.

No, that is not *parsing*. That is *generating text*.

But first we need to determine a time-of-day. I presume you want the first moment of the day.

Some dates in some time zones do not start at 00:00. So always let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day. We capture this moment as a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Amman" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

You ask for text to be generated in a format with no indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC. I recommend against this, as the reading of such text is ambiguous. But if you insist, *java.time* includes a predefined [format for the kind of text you desire](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME). This format is amongst those defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/3tuLn5).

> output: 2020-05-01T00:00:00

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Answer (score 0):

Use like that to convert one format to another:

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date date = originalFormat.parse("01 May 2020");
String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Do not use outdated date/time API. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn more about it.

Comment: It’s not outdated? Well apparently there’s more than one opinion about that. The official recommendation from Oracle since 2014 has been to use java.time, not `Date`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. I consider the old classes confusingly designed and — yes — outdated.

Comment: Admitted, if your Android minSDK is lower than 26, you need to weigh the advantages of the modern API against the cost of an external dependency, it’s not for free. In this case it would be a dependency on the backport of the code that is already part of Java 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, …  I think we can consider it rock solid.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It’s a very informative link, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable information that you have put in your comments.

Comment: @KrishnaSony These terrible date-time classes became legacy with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Sun, Oracle, IBM, and the JCP community agreed then to give up on those old classes. I suggest you do  the same.

Comment: Will give up soon on these classes, Thanks

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, Link  is really useful.